# Python CSV reader doesn't skip first line

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I'm trying to read from one and write to second CSV files. The problem is that I need to know how many lines are there in the input CSV file before reading it.

```
with open('csv/file.csv') as f:
    with open('output/output_{}.csv'.format(time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")), 'wb') as o:
        reader = csv.DictReader(f)
        reader.fieldnames.append('VAT added')
        rows = sum(1 for _ in reader)
        f.seek(0)
        writer = csv.DictWriter(o, fieldnames=reader.fieldnames)
        writer.writeheader()
        for n,line in enumerate(reader):
            print line
            print '{} lines remaining'.format(rows-n)
            code = line['number'].strip()
            ...
            writer.writerow(line)
```

The problem is that it reads the `header`line so it returns error after first iteration. Where is the problem?

Comment: Can you post exactly the error that you get? You can just pass over the first iteration.

Comment: What if you did `for n, line in enumerate(reader): if n > 0: <blah>`?

Comment: pandas' `read_csv` function has a `skiprows` and `header` params, either of which should be able to help you out here. http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your error description. It seems to differ between the title and the question body. One very obvious issue you have is that you are exhausting the `reader` generator, when you calculate its length (no that `file.seek` wont help you). Once you do this, you cant iterate it again. To get around the issue, convert it to a list. Then you can call `len` on it and iterate over it to your hearts content. That is assuming it's not a very large file. In which case creating a list might not be a good idea.

Comment: When I run this it runs to completion. I think it would help if you would tell us what error, issued by what line, in other words reproduce the stack trace. The problem could be in your data: for example, if your csv doesn't have a column headed 'number' you will get a key error.

Answer (score 0):

> **Question**  ...  it returns error after first iteration

Didn't know which **error** you get, but I get
**TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface**.

The reason is this line of code:

```
with open('output/output_{}.csv'.format(time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")), 'wb') as o:
```

Don't open a `csv` file in binary mode `wb`, change to `w`,e.g.

```
with open('output/output_{}.csv'.format(time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")), 'w') as o:
```

***Tested with Python:3.4.2***